# multilined regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to make my code easier to maintain, so I have met this problem

Would

```
re.compile(r'foo' # some comments
            '|bar'
)
```

Be the same as:

```
re.compile(r'foo|bar')#blabla
```

And this one:

```
re.compile(r"""foo #some comments
               bar""")
```

IdeaJ suggests something like this:

```
re.compile(r'foo'
           r'bar')
```

I've got thousands like this 'foobar' here.

I know that the third one may generate some unwanted \w
but what about the others?

What I wanted is just a regex matches foo OR bar

Comment: If you put a plus after the first substring to join the strings your first one should work.

Comment: Perhaps use string.join? `'|'.join(r'foo', r'bar'...)`

Comment: Thanks, but what if I got even more? do i have to add a '+' in each line like this? `r'foo'(LineBreak)+'bar'(LineBreak)+'foobar'`

Comment: @erlc that's a very beautiful way of using objects! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found this in Python docs http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation

```
 re.compile("[A-Za-z_]"       # letter or underscore
            "[A-Za-z0-9_]*"   # letter, digit or underscore
            )
```

Answer (score 4):

You can put your comments IN the regex by specifying the `re.VERBOSE` flag.

```
re.compile(r'''foo  # some comments
               |bar # some more comments
            ''', re.VERBOSE)
```

Shorthand for the flag is `re.X`.  [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE)

Comment: I always found it amusing that there's a shorthand for a verbose flag.